# What does 「たけた」mean in this sentence? 「他人に依存することばかりに たけた寄生虫」

Tags: words

These lines came from season 1 episode 1 of Kaguya-sama: Love is war at the 22:42 mark

> （かぐや）
> 人の姿をした家畜　プライドがなく　他人に依存することばかりに
> たけた寄生虫胸ばかりに栄養が行っている脳カラなんて おぞましい生き物

From my understanding of the context, Shinomiya got annoyed at Shirogane because he made a bento for Fujiwara and not for her. These lines were about Shinomiya's thoughts toward Fujiwara.

What does「たけた」mean in this sentence? I don't know what to look for in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up 長ける【たける】 (ichidan intransitive verb).

> #### [長ける](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%95%B7%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B)
>
> 1. to excel at; to be proficient at

> #### [長ける](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%95%B7%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B/)
>
> ３ ある方面にすぐれている。長じる。熟達している。「弁舌に―・ける」「世故 (せこ) に―・ける」